# Customizing kubectl output with go templates using custom function

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, go-templates

I'm trying to add a custom function In Go template for parsing the time in PodStatus and getting the absolute time for it.

Example for the custom function:

```
PodScheduled, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2021-12- 23T20:20:36Z")
Ready, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2021-12-31T07:36:11Z")

difference := Ready.Sub(PodScheduled)
fmt.Printf("difference = %v\n", difference)
```

I can use the built-in functions.

How I can use a custom function with the kubectl?

For example this lib:
https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig

Thanks :)

Comment: I made a simple program that reads input and a template and renders it with go text/template + sprig functions. You could output json with kubectl and pipe it into it https://github.com/bluebrown/jpipe

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you have (at least) 3 options:

1. Discouraged: Write your own client (instead of `kubectl`) that provides the functionality;
2. Encouraged: Use the shell to post-process the output from e.g. `kubectl get pods --output=json`) by piping the result through:

   - Either your Golang binary that reads from standard input
   - Or better a general-purpose JSON processing tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that would do this (and much more!)
3. For completeness, `kubectl` supports output formatting (`--output=jsonpath...`); although [`JSONPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) may be insufficient for this need;

See jq's documentation for [Dates](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight. 
My task: To get a report on how long time it takes for pods to start. we discided to use the information from PodStatus: Ready-PodScheduled=absolute delta What